# Chess rule clarification

Tags: rules

As my English chess vocabulary is very poor, I might pass near the solution but didn't see it... So here's my question :

> Can the white King go to d5 or f5 since the black Knight can't move ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the move is illegal. Even though the knight is pinned, the king can't move to the square under it's control.

Comment: Or think of it this way, the white king moves, the black knight takes and black wins. That's what would happen in a blitz game at least.

Comment: @ZL1Corvette: No, that would not even happen in a Blitz game. If after Kf5, Black takes the King, White may claim "illegal move" and win the game. That is *very* bad sportsmanship, but so are the rules.

Comment: White's move would  be illegal first. FIDE: An illegal move is completed once the opponent’s clock has been started. The opponent is entitled to claim a win before he has made his own move. However, if the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves, then the claimant is entitled to claim a draw before he has made his own move. Once the opponent has made his own move, an illegal move cannot be corrected unless mutually agreed without intervention of an arbiter. I was once told in Blitz you take the King instead of wasting time, but that might be wrong.